# Google Apps Script custom function - 2nd parameter array is empty

Tags: arrays, function, google-apps-script

Confirmed the logic of the function worked as expected by using arrays within the function.

However, once I passed arrays as parameters issue with the 2nd parameter reared up it's head.

Basically, the function loops through a 2D array that's a calendar, find the last (most recent) activity and then return the next value from the alt_activity range. If the previous activity is the last value from the alt_activity range, start from the start of the alt_activity range once more.

Sample data

```
/**
* Looks for the alternate workout in the LAST matching value within the calendar.
* @param {array} input The calendar array to be searched.
* @return The first match starting from the last row (WEEK) and column (DAY) of the @param.
* @customfunction
*/
function calender_search(calendar_range, alt_activities_range) 
{

  /**var calendar_range = [[ , ,          ,             ,            ,     'Chess'],
                        [ , ,          ,             ,   'Pilates',   'Elevate'],
                        [ , ,          ,  'Kundalini',  'Scrabble', 'Gardening'],
                        [ , , 'Darning',    'Crossword',       'Chess',   'Pilates']];        
*/                                       


 //var alt_activities_range = [ 'Chess', 'Pilates', 'Elevate', 'Kundalini', 'Scrabble', 'Gardening', 'Darning', 'Crossword'];

 
 
  for (let week = calendar_range.length - 1; week >= 0; week--) 
  {
    for (let day = calendar_range[week].length - 1; day >= 0; day--) 
    {
      //return calendar_range[week][day]; // test where the functionality gets to.
      return alt_activities_range[day]; // array is empty when passed in as a parameter
      

      if (alt_activities_range.indexOf(calendar_range[week][day]) > -1) 
      {
        //NOT entering this if statement!!! return (JSON.stringify(calendar_range)); 
/** 
        if (calendar_range[week][day] === alt_activities_range[alt_activities_range.length - 1]) 
        {
          return alt_activities_range[0];
        }
        // Go to index of match PLUS 1 for NEXT value to be returned
        return alt_activities_range[(alt_activities_range.indexOf(calendar_range[week][day]) + 1) % alt_activities_range.length];
      }
  */  
    }
  }
}
}
```

Table 1

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E | Column F | Column G | Column H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Wrkout Alternatives | Chess | Pilates | Elevate | Kundalini | Scrabble | Gardening | Darning |

| Column I |
| --- |
| Crossword |

Table 2

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E | Column F | Column G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | DAY 1 | DAY 2 | DAY 3 | DAY 4 | DAY 5 | DAY 6 |
| WEEK 1 |  |  |  |  |  | Chess |
| WEEK 2 |  |  |  |  | Pilates | Elevate |
| WEEK 3 |  |  |  | Kundalini | Scrabble | Gardening |
| WEEK 4 |  |  | Darning | Crossword | Chess | Pilates |

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.
When I pass in the first range (B6:G12) and the second range (B1:I1) the function fails to return the expected value which should be "Elevate". Simply an empty cell

However, when arrays are placed within the function with the same data as in the spreadsheet, the expected value ("Elevate") is returned. 
In the first scenario, it appears to be the case that the 2nd array passed in as a parameter is empty and the function never gets into the first IF statement. 
Thanks

Comment: No worries. I figured out a (crude) work around for the issue.  I copied the alt_wrkout_range parameter to a local variable (alt_wrkout_ARRAY). The first mention of the al_wrkout_range is within an IF clause so I'm guessing that this is where things stop working. An explicity variable seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a (crude) work around for the issue.  I copied the alt_wrkout_range parameter to a local variable (alt_wrkout_ARRAY). The first mention of the al_wrkout_range is within an IF clause so I'm guessing that this is where things stop working. An explicity variable seems to do the trick.

```
/**
* Looks for the alternate workout in the LAST matching value within the calendar.
* @param {array} input The calendar array to be searched.
* @return The first match starting from the last row (WEEK) and column (DAY) of the @param.
* @customfunction
*/
function calender_search(calendar_range, alt_activities_range) 
{
  var alt_activities_array=alt_activities_range[0].slice();

  for (let week = calendar_range.length - 1; week >= 0; week--) 
  {
    for (let day = calendar_range[week].length - 1; day >= 0; day--) 
    {

      if (alt_activities_array.indexOf(calendar_range[week][day]) > -1) 
      {
        if (calendar_range[week][day] === alt_activities_array[alt_activities_array.length - 1]) 
        {
          return alt_activities_array[0];
        }
        // Go to index of match PLUS 1 for NEXT value to be returned
        return alt_activities_array[(alt_activities_array.indexOf(calendar_range[week][day]) + 1) % alt_activities_array.length];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Perhaps someone will explain why the IF statement was causing the issue